# Installing libssh2 on debian

Tags: qemu

Hi I'm trying to install libssh2 for 64-bit. I'm using the following code for installation:

```
cd libssh2-1.4.3/

export CFLAGS="-mabi=64 -march=mips64r2"

./configure --with-libz --with-libgcrypt --with-libz-prefix=`pwd`/../../support__
libs/libs/zlib/ --with-libgcrypt-prefix=`pwd`/../../support_libs/``libs/extra --wii
thout-libssl-prefix --prefix=`pwd`/../../support_libs/libs/extra_2


make && make install
```

without using "export CFLAGS="-mabi=64 -march=mips64r2" it compiles the binaries in 32-bit and whem i use #export for 64-bit, it gives this configuration error::

```
checking for libgcrypt... no
configure: error: cannot find OpenSSL or Libgcrypt,
try --with-libssl-prefix=PATH or --with-libgcrypt-prefix=PATH
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified:

```
--with-libgcrypt-prefix=`pwd`/../../support_libs/``libs/extra
```

You have unnecessary double backquotes here: ``libs. Even though they shouldn't break the path, you don't need them.

Make sure that the directory you specified has correct version of the Libgcrypt library because configure script is complaining that it can't find it.

Comment: There is no any problem with the backquotes,i've removed them , and also i've libgrycpt ans other necessary library of 64-bit. But still i'm getting this error .

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that `--with-libgcrypt-prefix` path is correct and you have correct library version there, then try to go through the configure script itself and debug the part which fails. Compare with how it works when you try to compile for a 32bit target.